# Does weak-$\ast$ convergence with an exponential rate imply convergence of measures of sets with the same rate?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Assume that $\mu_n \to \mu$ in the weak-$\ast$ topology with the following rate for any compactly supported continuous function $f$: $$|\mu_n(f) - \mu(f)| \leq C_f e^{-n}.$$ Can we replace $f$ with the indicator function of a measurable set and get the same convergence rate property?

Comment: On what space do these functions and measures live?

Comment: Let's say, the space of unimodular lattices $SL(2, R) / SL(2, Z)$, with $\mu$ the measure we get from the Haar measure on $SL(2, R)$.

Answer (score 2):

Your hypothesis is never satisfied except in the trivial case when $||\mu_n-\mu||\le ce^{-n}$. (Which actually means the answer to your question is yes, but it's not the sort of yes I suspect you wanted.)

**Theorem** Suppose $K$ is a compact Hausdorff space, $a_n>0$, and for every $f\in C(K)$ we have $|\mu_n(f)-\mu(f)|\le c_f a_n$. Then $||\mu_n-\mu||\le ca_n$.

Proof. Say $b_n=1/a_n$. Suppose that $||\mu_n-\mu||\ne O(a_n)$. Then $||b_n(\mu_n-\mu)||$ is unbounded. Uniform Boundedness, aka Banach-Steinhaus, shows that there exists $f\in C(K)$ such that $b_n(\mu_n(f)-\mu(f))$ is unbounded.

Comment: Nice.  This also works if $K$ is only locally compact, replacing $C(K)$ with $C_0(K)$, the continuous functions vanishing at infinity.